# Unable to connect to SFTP after changing file permissions of /home folder

Tags: ubuntu, putty, sftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have ubuntu instance on amazon and due to some reasons, we have changed the permissions of folder /home to 777. Command : sudo chmod -R 777 /home

and now we are unable to connect to SFTP or via putty. So Please help us out how to solve this problem asap.

Comment: Are you using public key authentication? The OpenSSH server requires the files in `~/.ssh/` directory to have a `chmod` mask of `600`.

Comment: If you try `ssh -vv username@host` you may see more information regarding why you cannot connect, or at least how far into the process that it fails.  You've opened up permissions of /home to the world, so except for situations like what GiantTree commented, this should not be permission related.

Comment: @Xalorous yes, it will be permission related, but in the opposite way than you are thinking.  If your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file is writable by others then sshd considers it potentially compromised and untrusted... and ignores it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AWS does not have an interactive shell available, you need another way to fix the problem. I have used this method in the past, and it has worked for me:

- Disconnect the disk of your instance (let's call it instance A)
- Create a new instance (Instance B)
- Connect the disk of instance A as an additional disk on instance B
- Log on to instance B, mount the disk
- Fix the home directory permissions, safe values would be:

  ```
  chmod 755 /$mountpoint/home
  cd /$mountpoint/home
  find -type d | xargs chmod 750
  find -type f | xargs chmod 640
  find . -name '.ssh' -exec chmod 700 {} \;
  find . -name 'authorized_keys' -exec chmod 600 {} \;
  ```
- Unmount the disk
- Reconnect it to instance A
- Boot

Comment: For security's sake, I would make the chmod 750 * recursive, to get rid of those world writable bits on all the files inside /home.  `chmod 750 * -R`

Comment: Good catch, however this would make every file executable in the process? In that case, make all dirs 750 and all files 640. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Good point.  Though in this case it would be 'leaving' every file executable, since OP's already set everything to `777`.

Comment: No flies on you, mate!